# Android SQLite sending query as an email

Tags: android, sqlite

I was wondering if it was possible to send a query via email that is created through my app as a text file, or similar format that can be viewed on a pc. The  query i want to send is

```
public Cursor getExpiryData (){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor expiry = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_4 + " BETWEEN datetime('now', 'localtime') AND datetime('now', '+30 days')", null );
    return expiry;
}
```

Comment: Have you done any research on how to send an email through anrdroid ?

Comment: Some, but not sure if its possible to send a query made on sqlite

Comment: Save that query in a string and send the string as email from your android. There's plenty of help available online on how to send an email through android. Its possible if that's what you really need.

Comment: Im trying to find a tutorial now on how to save the query as a string.. thanks

Comment: Here is the good tutorial for sending email: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sending_email.htm

Comment: Do you want to email query or query result?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve data from cursor, use this piece of code:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
   do{
      String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("data"));
      // do what ever you want here
   }while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
cursor.close();
```

I don't know exactly the name of your columns. You can add your table data in list of object and follow the [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sending_email.htm) to send email tutorial.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to make string from cursor retrieve data and send it to email.
Formatting of string is all depend on you.